# SWT/JFace Minimize/Maximize EditorArea

Tags: swt, jface, rcp

I didn't manage to find any functionalities for minimizing/maximizing programatically. 
I want to minimize my editorArea when all the editors are closed.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround to minimize the editorArea. It's not very nice but it's doing the job.

```
      WorkbenchPage page = (WorkbenchPage)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
  IEditorReference[] editorReferences = page.getEditorReferences();
  if(editorReferences.length==0){
     page.getActivePerspective().setEditorAreaState(IStackPresentationSite.STATE_MINIMIZED);    
  }
```

I really don't like that cast but I cant get the concrete class.
Any suggestions for improving this?

Comment: This seems reasonable, though I'd at least check that the `IWorkbenchPage` returned from `getActivePage()` is an instance of `WorkbenchPage` before doing the cast.  I realize it's unlikely that anyone would bother to implement `IWorkbenchPage` and not extend `WorkbenchPage`, but it's possible.  (Unless, of course, you're building an RCP app constrained to the point where you can make this guarantee.)

Comment: `setEditorAreaState()` is defined in `Perspective` class, which is also _internal_, so you can't get around this.

Answer (score 2):

You can show/hide editor area using [`IWorkbenchPage`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPage.html).`setEditorAreaVisible()`. You could do this by adding [`IPerspectiveListener`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPerspectiveListener.html) to the window.

```
public void perspectiveChanged(IWorkbenchPage page,
        IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective, String changeId) {
    if (changeId == IWorkbenchPage.CHANGE_EDITOR_CLOSE) {
        if (page.isEditorAreaVisible() && page.getEditorReferences().length == 0)
            page.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
    }
}
```

While it is also possible to minimize editor area using `setPartState()` method of the page, this can't be done after all editors are closed. Even though the last editor reference is available in close editor event handler, the reference to `ILayoutContainer` has already been removed and thus can't be used to change the state.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I managed myself to hide the editor area when the EditorsReferences length is 0. The Problem is that i need to minimize it not to hide it.

Comment: @Lori Yeah, I got that, but I don't see a difference from usability point of view. When an editor is opened, the area will become visible again automatically.

Comment: I know, and i agree with you but my client doesn't agree with either of us:). If I can't find an other solution i will use this one.

Comment: I guess i will have to go with this solution. Thanks again

Comment: @Lori You can safely say that it is not feasible considering that a suitable alternative is available. Added a comment to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug on bugs.eclipse.com: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=29840 but i can't find the ZoomManagement.

Comment: Zoom in/out is maximize/restore, not minimize.